# How do I migrate from COMPILE_FLAGS to target_compile_options in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, emscripten

I have the following code in my CMakeLists.txt to set some compiler and linker flags for my emscripten project:

### Old, working code

```
set_target_properties(prolog_bfs PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0")
set_target_properties(prolog_bfs PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "--bind --emrun -s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0")
```

This works perfectly fine and my compiler gets called with the options as it should (I still wonder where the spaces after em++ are coming from though, but this is not an issue):

```
em++    -s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -std=gnu++17 -o xy.o -c xy.cpp
```

However, `COMPILE_FLAGS` and `LINK_FLAGS` are [**deprecated**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_FLAGS.html?highlight=compile_flags), so I **want to migrate to the new/recommended approach** of using `target_compile_options()` and `target_link_options()` instead.

Thus, I have changed my CMakeLists.txt like so:

### New approach

```
target_compile_options(prolog_bfs PUBLIC -s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1;-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0)
target_link_options(prolog_bfs PUBLIC --bind;--emrun;-s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1;-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0)
```

I understand that the target_*_options function requires to separate flags with a semicolon, which I did. Apart from that, I don't see any other major differences.

### The problem

Building my project with these changes will get the compiler called like this:

```
em++    -s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 -std=gnu++17 -o xy.o -c xy.cpp
```

Note that that the `-s` before the second flag is missing. I don't understand why it disappears. Interestingly, the first one stays there.

### Question

How do I transform my initial CMakeLists.txt code into the modern approach without losing the `-s`?

Comment: Why `;`? Remove all the `;` with just spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, CMake **de-duplicates** compile and link options. This is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_compile_options.html) for `target_compile_options` command. Also, the documentation suggests to use `SHELL:` prefix for avoid breaking groups because of that:

> The final set of compile or link options used for a target is constructed by accumulating options from the current target and the usage requirements of its dependencies. The set of options is de-duplicated to avoid repetition. While beneficial for individual options, the de-duplication step can break up option groups. For example, `-D A -D B` becomes `-D A B`. One may specify a group of options using shell-like quoting along with a `SHELL:` prefix. The `SHELL:` prefix is dropped, and the rest of the option string is parsed using the `separate_arguments()` `UNIX_COMMAND` mode. For example, `"SHELL:-D A" "SHELL:-D B"` becomes `-D A -D B`.

That is, in your case you may specify

```
target_compile_options(prolog_bfs PUBLIC "SHELL:-s USE_BOOST_HEADERS=1" "SHELL:-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0")
```