# How do I tell CMake to specify multiple linker script files to GCC?

Tags: gcc, cmake

I"m using CMake 3.17 and the GNU ARM toolchain and I'm trying to migrate a build from Eclipse to CMake. Part of the Eclipse build specifies multiple linker script files to use at link time so I set up my CMakeLists.txt file like this:

```
target_link_options(${application_name} PRIVATE
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mthumb 
    -mfloat-abi=hard 
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 
    -fmessage-length=0 
    -fsigned-char 
    -ffunction-sections 
    -fdata-sections 
    -flto 
    -Wall
    -Xlinker --gc-sections 
    -Wl,-Map,${map_file}
    -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/libs.ld
    -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/mem.ld
    -T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/sections.ld
)
```

But when I run `make` the `-T` option gets swallowed for the second and third files. Here's what I get when running `make VERBOSE=1` after successful compilation of all sources. The linker command line followed by a warning about missing `-T` options:

```
Linking CXX executable StartupSequence.elf
/D/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe    --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -g -Og -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -flto -Wall -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,StartupSequence.map -T C:/svn/startup_sequence/ldscripts/libs.ld C:/svn/startup_sequence/ldscripts/mem.ld C:/svn/startup_sequence/ldscripts/sections.ld @CMakeFiles/StartupSequence.dir/objects1.rsp  -o StartupSequence.elf  ../Drivers/CMSIS/DSP/Lib/libarm_cortexM4lf_math.a ../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/libmbedcrypto.a
d:/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: C:/svn/startup_sequence/ldscripts/sections.ld contains output sections; did you forget -T?
```

Why does the `-T` not get sent to the command line properly for the last two files?

I've tried separating the link script specification into three separate calls to `target_link_options` and enclosing each script specification in double quotes but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Try putting each argument in quotes? (e.g., `"-T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/libs.ld" "-T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/mem.ld"`)

Comment: I tried that but no dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, CMake **de-duplicates** compile and link options. That is, multiple `-T` options are combined into the single one.

CMake doesn't know which options are actually bonded with the further arguments, but provides a `SHELL:` mechanism for define such options:

```
target_link_options(${application_name} PRIVATE
  "SHELL:-T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/libs.ld"
  "SHELL:-T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/mem.ld"
  "SHELL:-T ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/sections.ld"
)
```

This mechanism is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/target_link_options.html) for `target_link_options` command.

---

The same mechanism works for compiler options passed to `target_compile_options`, see that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552844/how-do-i-migrate-from-compile-flags-to-target-compile-options-in-cmake) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553977/3440745) for it.

Comment: After seeing this and re-reading the docs I understand what's going on now and fixed my problem with this method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `-T` is interpreted as an single option. Glue `-T` with the path instead. Try:

```
-T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/libs.ld
-T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/mem.ld
-T${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ldscripts/sections.ld
```

Comment: This works as well. I selected the above as the answer because it seems to be a better "long term solution" and also taught me something important about CMake.